# How to close a port in my android device [i9515]?

Tags: security

When I used nmap to check the status of ports in my android device, I found out that port 514/tcp was open. I googled about the respective port and I found the following in the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

```
514 TCP     Remote Shell, used to execute non-interactive commands on a remote system (Remote Shell, rsh, remsh)
```

Is it safe to keep this port open?
If not, how can I close this port?

I ran the scan from a CentOS virtual machine in the same network.

Comment: I wonder which process was listening on port `514` on your device.